# How to average select values in a table by ROW not COLUMN

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with paper number, reviewer, originality, importance, soundness, and overall values. I'm trying to find an average of originality, importance, and soundness which are all integers per row (AKA for each paper).

I've only been able to average entire columns so far, which is useless to me as I need the values per individual row

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the 3 values and divide with 3:

```
select 
  papernumber, 
  (originality + importance + soundness) / 3 as averagevalue 
from tablename
```

If you want more precision with decimal places change to this:

```
select 
  papernumber, 
  (originality + importance + soundness) / 3.0 as averagevalue 
from tablename
```

Comment: You could just divide by 3.0 for that second one.

Comment: I guess so, just that I'm used to multiply by 1.0 in every such case.